# Code optimization for insertion sort advance analysis

Tags: c++, optimization

```
#include <string>
#include <numeric>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <cmath>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;


int main() {
    int n, n1, n2, index, max = 0;
    long cnt = 0;
    vector <int> arr;
    vector <int> arr1;
    cin >> n;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        cnt = 0, max = 0;
        cin >> n1;
        arr.clear();
        arr1.clear();
        for (int j = 0; j < n1; j++) {
            cin >> n2;
            arr.push_back(n2);
            if (n2 > max) max = n2;
        }
        for (int j = 0; j <= max; j++) {
            arr1.push_back(j);
            arr1[j] = 0;
        }
        for (int j = n1 - 1; j >= 0; j--) {
            index = arr[j] - 1;
            while (index > 0) {
                cnt += arr1[index];
                index -= (index & -index);
            }
            index = arr[j];
            while (index <= max) {
                arr1[index] += 1;
                index += (index & -index);
            }
        }
        cout << cnt << endl;
    }
}
```

I've been trying to solve the insertion sort advanced analysis but my code times out. Is there a way I can optimize the code more? The objective of the problem is to find the total number of times the array has to shift.
I've tried to use BIT for the first time.
n is for the number of tests.
n1 is for the amount of numbers that will be inputted.
arr is a vector to save the inputs.
arr1 is a vector to save the amount for each number. 
Sorry for the bad english.

Comment: Please include the problem you're trying to solve directly in the question, not through a link.

Comment: It would also help if you can explain your solution so that we don't have to reverse engineer it from your code.